# linux makefile equivalence? important

Tags: c++, windows, linux, makefile

I am a CS student but I CANNOT and please don't ask me why; I cannot use make and linux for my cs assignments. Is there anything in Windows 7 or Windows in general that is similar to make in linux? I want to do my assignments in windows instead of linux. What is the closest thing to make? I have eclipse but I wan't something simpler that I can still use simple commands and linking files in C++. Please help me. THanks (consider I'm a noob).

Comment: "please don't ask me why" - we kind of have to, to know whether you can't use linux, and therefore think there's no make, or whether you're expressly forbidden from using make.

Comment: Do you have a CS account? If so you can... SSH into your school server and just program in the school's linux environment. Many universities have this option, especially a linux vendor. UC R have it ^^, just in case you're a ucr student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily get a free (as in cost and freedom) `make` for Windows, both [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) provide them. In fact, I seem to recall that Microsoft compilers have their own make as well (`nmake` from memory, but I could be wrong).

If you can't use *any* `make`, then the next best thing is probablt `cmd` files to build your entire solution. But, if you do that, you lose the dependency checking where `make` shines.

Answer (score 2):

Is it that you can't use Linux, or that you can't use either Linux or make? There is a port of GNU Make for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

The [Microsoft SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx) has both MSBuild and `nmake` (which is kind of like Unix make).

For slightly more exotic tools, there are [scons](http://www.scons.org) and [cmake](http://www.cmake.org), but both are pretty different from make.

Comment: well I just dont have acces to linux thus make commands that they teach me in school. I wanna still compile and run my C++ programs in windows that is something similar to make, maybe in terminal, etc. Thanks

Comment: @user: Now you're really getting confusing - they teach you linux and make at school and yet you can't use them?

Comment: @user593301 - then in that case, get a port of make (either from my link or from paxdiablo's links to cygwin or gnuwin32). make is just a tool that reads a file that has the actual compiler commands specified. But if they expect you to use Linux-type stuff, like using Linux libraries in your code or they will only test your code on Linux, then I would recommend installing Linux. You can do this by installing a virtual machine software like [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) into Windows and then installing Linux into it.

Comment: well i would rather do the stuff from home. I have a long commute. So the GNU make automatically allows me to use make commands from command promt? thanks

Comment: i dont really think I will be using much of linux libraries since I'm sure the C++ std is the same as in linux? I assume

Comment: @user593301 - GNU make is the `make` command they're teaching you. `make` reads [Makefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile#Makefile_structure) that specify compiler commands, dependencies between modules, and whatnot. If you want to emulate the Linux environment school uses, you can do it on your own computer at home with, as I just said, [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) and installing the Linux they use. And I have no idea what they're teaching you in school - they might only use the C++ standard library stuff, or they might do platform specific stuff. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [maven](http://maven.apache.org).  There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's starting to gain traction.

Comment: i installed make on windows (GNU) but i click on make nothing happens. Does installing make allow me to use make commands from the command prompt in windows just like it would be in linux?

Answer (score 0):

not to mention Ant (java) and nAnt (C#). They both run on Windows.

Also, Perforce's Jam, quite good for C/C++ builds, due to its divining dependencies on the fly. http://www.perforce.com/jam/jam.html

And the X11/X-Windows *imake* runs on Win32 as well. http://www.snake.net/software/imake-stuff/imake-faq.html#TOC_4

Lots o'choices.

Frankly, I don't see the attraction of XML for this sort of stuff. Makefiles have always seemed pretty obvious (and simple) to me.

Comment: k thanks guys..ill try cygwin for now..and go from there.. i just didnt know where to start.. all the classes at college are all linux oriented. IDK why. most of the world out there is windows programming

Comment: I remember using imake in 2003, and noting it was obsolete for at least 10 years back then.